# How do I read Java's API documentation?

Tags: java, class, methods, javadoc

I have some confusion on what class name to use from the documentation.

If I want to use the method `getLength(Object name)` from the `Array` class the compiler accepts `java.lang.reflect.Array.getLength(nameOfArray)` but not `java.lang.Object.getLength(nameOfArray)`. Though the picture of the API documentation linked below seems to imply to me that both classes are linked to the Array classes method.

[Java API documentation example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nqMJs.png)

Comment: Your question has nothing to do with 'class paths'. It is about *classes*, and class names, and inheritance.

Comment: So class.class.class is a class, ahh thanks for clearing that up :) So would class.class also be a class?

Comment: Oh and when is it appropriate to say class path?

Comment: Also thanks for editing my question :D, i didn't know you could use single quotes to highlight code like that. First question newbie here haha, pardon the errors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason you see them linked is that `Object` is a **Superclass** of `Array`.

In Java, `Object` is the superclass of **all** classes.

> The Object class, in the java.lang package, sits at the top of the
>   class hierarchy tree. Every class is a descendant, direct or indirect,
>   of the Object class.

More over here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/objectclass.html

Each such child class (Array class in this case) inherits some methods from the superclass (Object class in this case).

If the child class wishes to change any of these variables or methods that it inherits from the superclass, then it will **override** those. In addition, the **child class itself may have its own variables and methods which have got nothing to do with the superclass**. That is the case in the example you've shown i.e. Array is a data-structure that has a length, but its parent Object does not have a length.

**Note:** Please read about *Inheritance in Java*. 
In addition, also read about *access specifiers* (because private members are not inherited), *keywords* (eg. `final` variables can't change value, `final` methods cannot be overriden, `final` classes can't be subclassed). Good luck!

Comment: Thank you! If the object class had an implementation of 'getLength(Object name)' would it work? The only methods and variables not inherited are overridden classes correct?

Comment: Array has a length hence you can 'implement' getLength on it. Not sure what you are asking in the next question. Please search online for Inheritance in Java and read some material and tutorials. Good luck!

Comment: I've updated the answer with some information on overriding.

Answer (score 3):

> If I want to use the method getLength(Object name) from the Array class the compiler accepts `java.lang.reflect.Array.getLength(nameOfArray)`

Correct, because that's where the method is.

> but not `java.lang.Object.getLength(nameOfArray)`.

Incorrect, because there is no such method in the `java.lang.Object` class.

> Though the API documentation linked below seems to imply to me that both class paths are linked to the `Array` classes method.

No it doesn't. The meaning of the part in your picture is that the second class extends the first class.

Answer (score 1):

That documentation example shows that `Array` is a child of `Object`, not that you can use them interchangably.

Answer (score 0):

`Array` extends `Object`. It means that Any method available for object is available for an Array, but the inverse is not true.

Consider this example. replace `Array` with `Student` and `Object` with `Human`. `Student extends Human`. Lets say that `Human` has `getDateOfBirth` method. `Student` also has `getGrades` method. On `Student` you can call `getDateOfBirth` and `getGrades`, while on `Human` you can only call `getDateOfBirth` because grades are not defined for babies.

Note that `Object` is the superclass of all other classes. As a result it has least number of methods.